# droppedBefore event doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, redips.drag

Using REDIPS awesome drag and drop library I've been trying to work out why the `droppedBefore` event doesn't fire.

I've cut down bare bones example and uploaded the files here for an easy repro: http://tempsend.com/8B0DF444D3 and here is a live snippet to show you the issue quickly.

```js
"use strict";

// define redips_init variable
var redips = {},  // redips container
 rd = REDIPS.drag,    // reference to the REDIPS.drag library
    msg;

// redips initialization
redips.init = function () {
 msg = document.getElementById('message');

 // how to display disabled elements
 rd.style.borderDisabled = 'solid'; // border style for disabled element will not be changed (default is dotted)
 rd.style.opacityDisabled = 60;  // disabled elements will have opacity effect
 // initialization
 rd.init();
 // only "smile" can be placed to the marked cell
 //rd.mark.exception.d8 = 'smile';
    // shift DIV elements with animation
 rd.shift.animation = true;
    // disabled elements will have opacity effect
 rd.style.opacityDisabled = 50;
    // set hover color
 rd.hover.colorTd = '#9BB3DA';
 // prepare handlers
 rd.event.cloned = function () {
     // display message
     var pos = rd.getPosition();
     msg.innerHTML += ' FROM ' + pos[1] + ' ' + pos[2] + '<br>'
 };
 rd.event.droppedBefore = function (targetCell) {
     alert('THIS EVENT FIRED YAY@!!!!');     //<-- SHOW THIS TO WIN THE PRIZE!
 };

 rd.event.deleted = function (cloned) {
  // if cloned element is directly moved to the trash
     if (cloned) {
   var pos = rd.getPosition();
   msg.innerHTML += ' TO ' + pos[1] + ' ' + pos[2] + '<br>';
  }
  else {
   msg.innerHTML += 'Deleted';
  }
 };

};



// add onload event listener
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', redips.init, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', redips.init);
}
```

```css
/*
Darko Bunic
http://www.redips.net/
Jun, 2011.
*/

body {
 font-family: arial;
 margin: 0px; /* for IE6 / IE7 */
}

/* add bottom margin between tables */
#table1,
#table2 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* drag container */
#redips-drag {
 margin: auto;
 width: 680px;
}

/* set border for images inside DRAG region - exclude image margin inheritance */
/* my WordPress theme had some funny margin settings */
#redips-drag img {
 margin: 1px;
}

/* drag objects (DIV inside table cells) */
.redips-drag {
 cursor: move;
 margin: auto;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
 margin-top: 1px;
 z-index: 10;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 10pt; /* needed for cloned object */
 width: 140px;
 height: 150px;  /* objects height */
 line-height: 20px;
 /* round corners */
 border-radius: 4px; /* Opera, Chrome */
 -moz-border-radius: 4px; /* FF */
}


/* drag objects border for the first table */
.t1 {
 border: 2px solid #499B33;
}
/* drag object border for the second table */
.t2 {
 border: 2px solid SteelBlue;
}
/* cloned objects - third table */
.t3 {
 border: 2px solid #FF8A58;
}
/* allow / deny access to cells marked with 'mark' class name */
.redips-mark {
 color: white;
 background-color: #9B9EA2;
}
/* trash cell */
.redips-trash {
 color: white;
 background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.icontext {
    color: black;
}

/* tables */
div#redips-drag table {
 background-color: #e0e0e0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}


/* input elements in dragging container */
div#redips-drag input {
 cursor: auto;
}
 /* height for input text in DIV element */
 div#drag #d13 input {
  height: 13px;
 }
 /* height for dropdown menu in DIV element */
 div#drag #d5 select {
  height: 20px;
 }

/* table cells */
div#redips-drag td {
 height: 32px;
 border: 1px solid white;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 10pt;
 padding: 2px;
}

/* "Click" button */
.button {
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 background-color: #6A93D4;
 color: white; 
 border-width: 1px;
 width: 44px;
 padding: 0px;
}


/* toggle checkboxes at the bottom */
.checkbox {
 margin-left: 13px;
 margin-right: 14px;
 width: 13px; /* needed for IE ?! */
}


/* message cell */
.message_line {
 padding-left: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 3px;
 font-size: 10pt;
 color: #888;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <meta name="description" content="Description">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"><!-- "position: fixed" fix for Android 2.2+ -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dragDrop_files/12112015.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.redips.net/my/preview/REDIPS_drag/redips-drag-min.js"></script>
  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./dragDrop_files/script.js"></script>
  <title>Droppable Event</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  
 <div style="background-color:#eee;padding:10px;text-align:center;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold">A</div>
  <br>
  <div id="redips-drag">
  <!-- tables inside this DIV could have draggable content -->
   <div style="background-color:#eee;padding:10px;text-align:center;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold"><a href="">Drop Before Event Not Working</a></div>
        
   <table id="FSU4">
    <colgroup><col width="160"><col width="160"><col width="160"><col width="40"><col width="160"></colgroup>
    <tbody><tr height="150px" style="background-color: #eee">
     <td class="redips-trash" title="adsf"><div id="34563463" class="redips-drag t3 redips-clone" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;"><a href="http://abc.com.au" title="abc">sdafsfd</a><BR></div></td>
     <td class="redips-trash" title="ertrt"><div id="2765657" class="redips-drag t3 redips-clone" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;"><a href="http://abc.com.au" title="abc">fghdfghH</a></div></td>
     <td class="redips-trash" title="erter"><div id="3456347" class="redips-drag t3 redips-clone" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;"><a href="http://abc.com.au" title="abc">ljkljhsdf</a></div></td>
     <td class="redips-mark"></td>
     <td class="redips-mark"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="150px">
     <td class="redips-mark"></td>
     <td class="redips-mark"></td>
     <td class="redips-mark"></td>
     <td class="redips-mark"></td>
     <td class="redips-mark"></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table>
   
   <div  id="message" > </div>

   <div><input type="button" value="Save1" class="button" onclick="save(&#39;plain&#39;)" title="Send content to the server (it will only show accepted parameters)"><span class="message_line">Save content of the first table (plain query string)</span></div>
   <div><input type="button" value="Save2" class="button" onclick="save(&#39;json&#39;)" title="Send content to the server (it will only show accepted parameters)"><span class="message_line">Save content of the first table (JSON format)</span></div>
   <div><input type="radio" name="drop_option" class="checkbox" onclick="setMode(this)" value="multiple" title="Enabled dropping to already taken table cells" checked="true"><span class="message_line">Enable dropping to already taken table cells</span></div>
   <div><input type="radio" name="drop_option" class="checkbox" onclick="setMode(this)" value="single" title="Disabled dropping to already taken table cells"><span class="message_line">Disable dropping to already taken table cells</span></div>
   <div><input type="radio" name="drop_option" class="checkbox" onclick="setMode(this)" value="switch" title="Switch content"><span class="message_line">Switch content</span></div>
   <div><input type="radio" name="drop_option" class="checkbox" onclick="setMode(this)" value="switching" title="Switching content continuously"><span class="message_line">Switching content continuously</span></div>
   <div><input type="radio" name="drop_option" class="checkbox" onclick="setMode(this)" value="overwrite" title="Overwrite content"><span class="message_line">Overwrite content</span></div>
   <div><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="toggleDeleteCloned(this)" title="Remove cloned object if dragged outside of any table" checked="true"><span class="message_line">Remove cloned element if dragged outside of any table</span></div>
   <div><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="toggleConfirm(this)" title="Confirm delete"><span class="message_line">Confirm delete</span></div>
   <div><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="toggleDragging(this)" title="Enable dragging" checked="true"><span class="message_line">Enable dragging</span></div>
  <div id="redips_clone" style="height: 1px; width: 1px;"></div></div>
 
</body></html>
```

To see the problem Run Code Snippet and drag a box onto another box, an alert should be shown saying: THIS EVENT FIRED YAY@!!!!

I've taken the above code from http://www.redips.net/my/preview/REDIPS_drag/example26/ which has a working `rd.event.droppedBefore` event. I've compared my cut down repro with the example 10 times over and still can't determine why the event isn't being fired? The other 2 events `rd.event.cloned` and `rd.event.deleted` both work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it does not work because of this code,

Original Code:

```
<tr height="150px" style="background-color: #eee">
                    <td class="redips-trash" title="adsf"><div id="34563463" class="redips-drag t3 redips-clone" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;"><a href="http://abc.com.au" title="abc">sdafsfd</a><BR></div></td>
                    <td class="redips-trash" title="ertrt"><div id="2765657" class="redips-drag t3 redips-clone" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;"><a href="http://abc.com.au" title="abc">fghdfghH</a></div></td>
                    <td class="redips-trash" title="erter"><div id="3456347" class="redips-drag t3 redips-clone" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;"><a href="http://abc.com.au" title="abc">ljkljhsdf</a></div></td>
                    <td class="redips-mark"></td>
                    <td class="redips-mark"></td>
```

Fixed Code:

```
 <tr height="150px" style="background-color: #eee">
                        <td  title="adsf"><div id="34563463" class="redips-drag t3 redips-clone" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;"><a href="http://abc.com.au" title="abc">sdafsfd</a><BR></div></td>
                        <td title="ertrt"><div id="2765657" class="redips-drag t3 redips-clone" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;"><a href="http://abc.com.au" title="abc">fghdfghH</a></div></td>
                        <td title="erter"><div id="3456347" class="redips-drag t3 redips-clone" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;"><a href="http://abc.com.au" title="abc">ljkljhsdf</a></div></td>
                        <td class="redips-mark"></td>
                        <td class="redips-mark"></td>
```

The Reason is simple either you put class="redips-drag orange redips-clone" or class="redips-trash" dont give both to an element. You gave `td redips-trash` and inside gave `div redips-drag` thats a confusion i think. As per example link i found that buggy. if you want to make it sure it doesn't make duplicates then remove `redips-clone`.

Comment: Without the TD element className's of `redips-trash` , duplicates are created :( Thank you for pointing me toward the root cause +1. If you can work out how to still honor that className so duplicates aren't created I would be ever so grateful

Comment: so if you dont want to create duplicate and only want to drag original div then replace this `class="redips-drag t3 "` to this `class="redips-drag t3 redips-clone"`

Comment: The behaviour I wanted is possible with your answer of removing `class="redips-trash"` , and in the droppedBefore event using this code to delete the clone `rd.obj.ParentNoderemoveChild(rd.obj);` - thanks again :)